# Ionic 4 date type input field not being filled with variable

Tags: php, angular, ionic4

I am trying to set a default date for an input field of date data type.

This default date comes from a php file and is stored in a variable inside the .ts file: `fecha_inicial`.

PHP function to get the date: `date("d/m/Y");`.

`fecha_inicial` varibale is correctly filled, as `console.log('fecha_inicio',this.fecha_inicio)`shows a date like 17/09/2020. The variable is initialised in ngOnInit()

Then, the code I use for the input is the follwing:

```
<input type="date" data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" value="fecha_inicio" [(ngModel)]="fecha_inicio">
```

However, the input field is not being filled with the value of the variable... I think it might be a data type problem. Any ideas on how to solve it?

**The code works if instead of type="date" i write type="text"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Angular DatePipe

```
<input [ngModel]="fecha_inicio | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="fecha_inicio = $event" type="date" name="fecha_inicio"/>
```

Additional information [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: I do not understand why should I use `(valueChange)="changeDate($event)"`. I want the `fecha_inicio` received in the .ts file to be the default value appearing in the input field, which the user will be able to change if he/she wants to.

Comment: Also, my code works if instead of type="date" i write type="text"

Comment: Try to use then the Date Pipe `<input [ngModel]="fecha_inicio | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="fecha_inicio = $event" type="date" name="fecha_inicio"/>`

Comment: @ÒscarFuentes Tell me if this solution worked for you to update my answer

Comment: when I input different dates, it fails: `Tab3Page.html:47 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "18/09/2020" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'`

Comment: I think your date format could be the problem. Try to replace yours "/" into "-". You can use `dateCreated = formatDate(`${dateCreated}`.replaceFunction('/','-'),'full','es-ES');
`

Comment: I've replaced it in PHP, much easier. However, still same error: `'Unable to convert "18-09-2020" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'`

Comment: Try to add `.toDate()` to your fecha_inicio in the pipe:  `[ngModel]="fecha_inicio.toDate() | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" ` . Tell me if this work.

Comment: I think I know why: we are trying to introduce the day as the month, so there is not an 18 month

Comment: I get the following error: `ERROR TypeError: _co.fecha_inicio.toDate is not a function`